# How should i version control a software that has multiple variants for multiple customers?

Tags: git, gitlab

I use master branch as production, and dev as development, as protected branches, and use topic branches to develop the codebase, but if a new customer comes up with unique ideas, should i start customer specific protected branches (master and dev), or whole new remote project for them?

Edit: To be more accurate, i mean the variants are **strictly individual**. So i have the base software *A*, variant *B* and variant *C*, these 3 variants only shares the *A* codebase, modifies *B* and *C* are 100% distinct, have different versions as well. In the future i may have to set up even more variants.

Comment: This is one of those … it depends comment. You could create a feature in master and configure your software to enable that feature just for that customer. Look up feature flagging as an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> these 3 variants only shares the A codebase, modifies B and C are 100% distinct, have different versions as well

Then yes, they need their own integration branches (branches where you merge multiple topic branch to make a new release).

Their merge workflow lifecycle will be independent from software A, and they need their own production maintenance.

---

The alternative is to use [GitLab Feature flags](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/operations/feature_flags.html), based on [Unleash](https://docs.getunleash.io/user_guide/unleash_overview), to maintain a unique software with the ability to  toggle a feature on and off to subsets of users.
Then you would maintain a unique software, but that seems more complex.